# How to change the current row values?

Tags: html, jquery

The below code retrieves the current row and makes changes to the first of four values ([0] being the first value). I've used console.log which displays the output but I want the changes to occur for that row. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(".editPersonnelBtn").on("click", function (e) {
    var $currentRow     = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").text()[0].html = ("po");
    console.log($currentRow)    
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<table id="personnelTable">
</table>
```

I have dynamically added rows

```
var markup = "";
markup += '<tr>';
markup += '<td>' + result.data[0].firstName +   result.data[0].lastName + result.data[0].jobTitle+ result.data[0].email + '</td>';
markup += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editPersonnelBtn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editPersonnelModal" data-id = '+result.data[0].id+'> <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-fw"> </i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm deletePersonnelBtn" data-bs-toggle ="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePersonnelModal" data-id= '+ result.data[0].id+ '> <i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-fw"></i> </td>';
markup += '</tr>';
$("#personnelTable").append(markup);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML with your question.

Comment: I have added the HTML along with the rows being created

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the inner html of the first four tds in the row where the button was clicked to po, you can do the following:

```js
$(".editPersonnelBtn").on("click", function (e) {
    var $currentRow     = $(this).closest("tr");
    var tds = $currentRow.find("td");
    for (let index = 0; index < Math.min(4, tds.length); index++) {
        tds[index].innerHTML = "po";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input class="editPersonnelBtn" type="button" value="click me"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input class="editPersonnelBtn" type="button" value="click me"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input class="editPersonnelBtn" type="button" value="click me"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

We find the row, get the tds, loop with an index up to 3 (or `tds.length` if there are not enough columns) and set the `innerHTML` to po.